# Change getCPtr() visibility of a shared_ptr

Tags: java, c++, swig

I am currently using swig to generate Java code.

I have two swig modules (`module1` and `module2`) that will create two packages (`fr.package1` and `fr.package2`). The generated classes of `fr.package2` needs to use the generated classes of the other package. In order to achieve that, I need to change the visibility of the `getCPtr()` method to `public`.

As written in the [documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/Java.html#Java_code_typemaps), I added in my interface file :

```
SWIG_JAVABODY_PROXY(public, public, SWIGTYPE)
SWIG_JAVABODY_TYPEWRAPPER(public, public, public, SWIGTYPE)
```

In `module1`, I also use a `shared_ptr` for a class, like this :

```
%module module1

%include <boost_shared_ptr.i>
%inline %{
    #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
%}
%{
    #include "foo.h"
%}
SWIG_JAVABODY_PROXY(public, public, SWIGTYPE)
SWIG_JAVABODY_TYPEWRAPPER(public, public, public, SWIGTYPE)
%shared_ptr(foo)
%include "foo.h"
```

When I run `swig`, the generated classes have a public visibility for `getCPtr()`, except for the class `foo`.

Why isn't it working when I use `%shared_ptr` ? Is there a way to put the visibility of `getCPtr()` to public when using `%shared_ptr` ?

Comment: If you put the `%shared_ptr` directive before the `SWIG_JAVABODY` macros does that fix it?

Comment: @Flexo No, it changes nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing we need to address is why the shared_ptr macro breaks this. The answer lies in what the shared_ptr macro itself actually does. In short it's provides a bunch of extra, specialised typemaps, including the javabody typemap which supplies the getCPtr implementation amongst other things.

The next chunk of this answer rapidly becomes a discussion on how typemap matching logic works inside SWIG. You can safely skip it if you don't really care.

So the initial problem is that the extra typemaps being given for foo here "beat" the SWIGTYPE ones, because they're more specific. (SWIGTYPE is basically a low precedence wildcard stand in for any type without anything more specific). This immediately leads to an obvious idea: change SWIGTYPE to be foo in both the modifier controlling macros. That however doesn't work, because we end up with two competing `%typemap(javabody) foo`s getting supplied. And in that scenario the last one seen wins. So if we changed the interface to be more like this:

```
%shared_ptr(foo)
SWIG_JAVABODY_PROXY(public, public, foo)
SWIG_JAVABODY_TYPEWRAPPER(public, public, public, foo)
```

Then the javabody typemap with public wins out. But that might not be what we want, because after all if the shared_ptr macro is changing the javabody typemap it's probably doing that for a reason right? We could inspect both and see, but I've not actually done that right now, because there's a better solution anyway.

If we look inside boost_shared_ptr.i it turns out there's a way given to control the modifiers of the javabody that it provides also. If we set our module to now be this:

```
%module module1
#define SWIG_SHARED_PTR_TYPEMAPS(CONST, TYPE...) SWIG_SHARED_PTR_TYPEMAPS_IMPLEMENTATION(public, public, CONST, TYPE)

%include <boost_shared_ptr.i>

%shared_ptr(foo)

// ...
```

Then it works as you hoped. Note that it's really important our `#define` comes before anything else has included the shared pointer header.

Comment: This gives me error: `Error: previous definition of 'SWIG_SHARED_PTR_TYPEMAPS'`

Comment: Is that error from SWIG itself or the compiler you built the output with? Which version of swig are you running?

Comment: I alse have this error:

`CommonModule.i:5: Error: Macro 'SWIG_SHARED_PTR_TYPEMAPS' redefined,
/wig-4.1.1/share/swig/4.1.1/java/boost_shared_ptr.i:4: Error: previous definition of 'SWIG_SHARED_PTR_TYPEMAPS'.`